# How to send Multiple Requests and fetch data to update multiple UI Labels in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, nsurl

I have to call two web services simultaneously and then update the UI components, say, two labels (each getting data from different service response). What is the best possible way to achieve this?

I tried `NSURL sendSynchronousRequest`, **but it takes huge time.**

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try with `sendAsynch..` if it takes huge time.

Comment: I can not update the UI if i use Async.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But you can update the UI in the main thread know

Answer (score 0):

For your Comment,  You need to do request with `dispatch_async` and update in the main Thread

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                // Request the WebService calls here
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Update the UILabel's here
                });


            });
```

Comment: I received null response for this! However I am using - NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

Comment: Try this `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];` and also ensure the URL is corrct